# Instance Declaration of Result Day using MySQL-simple

Tags: mysql, haskell

I'm trying to retrieve a date from my MySQL table using the MySQL-simple package in Haskell and I keep getting the following error:

```
mysql-simple.hs:12:17:
    No instance for (Database.MySQL.Simple.Result.Result Day)
      arising from a use of `query_'
```

'record_date' is a column in the MySQL table with a type of Date and it is not allowed to be null.

My source code is below, can anyone shed some light on the appropriate way to retrieve a date from MySQL in Haskell?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Text
import Data.Time.Clock (UTCTime)
import Data.Time.Calendar (Day)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Database.MySQL.Simple

main = do
        conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo { connectUser = "haskell", connectPassword = "hpasswd", connectDatabase = "hdbase" }
        rset <- query_ conn "select symbol, record_date, low, high, open, close from performance where symbol = 'AAPL' order by record_date desc limit 5"
        forM_ rset $ \(s, r, l, h, o, c) -> do
                print $ unpack s ++ (show (l::Double)) ++ (show (h::Double)) ++ (show (o::Double)) ++  (show (c :: Double))
                print $ show (r :: Day)
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace `:: Day` with `:: UTCTime`?

Comment: Regrettably no, I get the same error but with 'Result UTCTime' in place of 'Result Day'.

Answer (score 1):

After some further exploration and trying to execute the code from ghci I recieved an error which stated that there was overlapping definitions in 2 different libraries and as GHCI could not figure out which was the appropriate one to use it had to bail out.  The message:

```
GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
   get_current_timezone_seconds
whilst processing object file
   /home/user/.cabal/lib/time-1.5.0.1/ghc-7.6.3/HStime-1.5.0.1.o
This could be caused by:
   * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
   * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
   * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
     loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.
```

Looking at the 'Loading package' statements which preceded this error I noticed that the system was trying to load time-1.4.0.1 and then time-1.5.0.1.  As I've been trying to find the preferred library for accessing MySQL I had installed persistent-mysql, hdbc-mysql and a couple of others.  In turn I had uninstalled each but apparently some cruft got left behind.  After removing the time-1.5.0.1 library I recompiled my original code and ran it without issue.

In the end it seems a case where ghc was outputting an appropriate error message but I didn't have enough information to determine the root cause (ie 2 different definitions of Day brought on by 2 different versions of the time package).  All fixed now though... yeesh.